# Are prepositions constant with word types of the same stem?

Tags: preposition

We usually learn the preposition along with the verb/noun/adjective. In Arabic, the preposition is the same with these different word types. Is it in German?

Examples:

- abhängen/abhängig/Abhängigkeit von
- eignen/Eignug für
- bitten/Bitte um

Can we consider this a rule, and thus facilitating learning of prepositions? Or are there many exceptions, and thus it is not recommended to consider this as a rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most German verbs can go with more than one preposition, depending on the meaning. But yes, if you settled for a certain meaning, all derived words take the preposition with them.

> Dieses Medikament eignet sich für Kinder. — Es ist geeignet für Kinder. – Eignung für Kinder
>
> Dieses Medikament eignet sich gegen Würmer. — Es ist geeignet gegen Würmer. — Eignung gegen Würmer

---

About your notion of verb/adjective/noun, it's not that simple in German. In addition to your adjective *abhängig*, there are also two different *Partizip II* of *abhängen*. There's also a *Partizip I*, and all have a corresponding noun.

> abhängen
>
> abhängend — der/die/das Abhängende (built from the Partizip I)
>
> abgehängt — der/die/das Abgehängte (built from the Partizip II)
>
> abgehangen — der/die/das Abgehangene (built from the Partizip II)
>
> abhängig — der/die/das Abhängige (built from the Adjektiv)

*Abhang* is the base noun for the verb *abhängen*, and *Abhängigkeit* is a further noun built on the *Adjektiv*. Often there is another common noun with *-ung* instead of *-heit* or *-keit*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the beautiful answer. If abhängig is the second participle, then what is abgehangen?

Comment: You are right about that one. There are two *Partizip II*: *abgehängt* and *abgehangen*, both meaning a different thing. *Abhängig* is an adjective, meaning another different thing. The difference shows up with the passive/futur helper *werden*: *Er ist ab**ge**hangen worden. Er ist ab**ge**hängt worden. Er ist abhängig **ge**worden.*

Answer (score 1):

That depends on what you mean by "this". What is generally the case is that if there is, say, a noun "governing" a certain preposition and if there is a corresponding verb and/or adjective governing a preposition, then these prepositions are the same. **In other words, within a given group of nouns/adjective/verbs you would not expect *different* prepositions**.

However, it is not a reliable rule to assume that if, say, there is a noun governing a certain preposition then the verb will also govern a preposition in the first place. First of all, such a verb may not exist at all. But even if it does, it is frequent that, for instance, the noun governs a preposition while the verb requires an accusative complement (*Jagd auf Tiere / Tiere jagen, Kritik an Anna / Anna kritisieren*) or a dative complement (*Begegnung mit Jonas / Jonas begegnen*).

---

Further reading:

- *Helbig/Buscha*, Deutsche Grammatik, 2001, p. 269-72.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I deduce from the answers if there is a verb or/and adjective or/and noun derived from the same stem and has a certain preposition for a certain meaning, then the preposition would be the same.